# Is there a way to skip jQuery/Backbone/Underscore code, when stepping through JS with debugger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, backbone.js

When using Chrome debugger to step through the code in my JS apps , I often find myself wading through backbone/underscore/jQuery code which I'm not interested in following.  Is there anyway to step through *my* code, but have the debugger skip code which is part of these libraries?

Answer (score 3):

I just spent three days living inside chrome's debugger doing exactly this.

The trick is to set a breakpoint on and the next line after the Backbone/jQuery/Underscore code and F8 when you get there.

Like

```
for(_(obj).each(function(v,k,l){
    console.log( k,v,l);
});
```

Set your breakpoints on the `for` line and the `console` line. F11 down to the for line, then F8 and then continue your stepping.

It's a little bit of a pain to set up but since toggling breakpoints off is easier than setting them initially when you have it set up its easy to maintain.

Comment: It's nice to hear I'm not the only one ;) Interesting - that makes sense. I guess this gets a little more painful when it's asynchronous/event based code though...

Comment: Yeah it does. Allow me to plug my validation framework for Backbone models though! (hence the hours of debugging). http://github.com/toddself/Backbone.Validator  it would be nice if you could mark an entire file as "don't debug" though...

Comment: I'll take a look at your validation framework - thanks.  Do you happen to know where we might put in a request for the 'don't debug this file' feature?

Comment: @UpTheCreek http://webkit.org! The debugger is part of webkit itself (although I'm positive both Apple and Google have their own patches they apply downstream). Let me know if you find the framework useful.  I'm developing it as I am adding validation and test cases to my models for my job, so I've been updating it frequently.  Right now it's passing 81 test cases locally (but failing on 1), so it seems to be getting stable!

Answer (score 2):

In most debuggers, you have a "Step out" (of current function), so you can use that whenever you step into the top-most levels of the libraries you want to skip.

EDIT: Btw, step out goes from current location to the return in the current function. I haven't used debuggers too much, so I can't tell what would happen if you step out of a function with asynchronous calls in it. I can only imagine it would exit the function and the async call would go on about its business while you step into something else.

Comment: Yes, there is a step out feature in chrome debugger, but ideally I don't want to be presented with the library code at all. Out of sight is out of mind - and when it comes to debugging, unfortunately my mind's 'stack' is rather limited ;)

Comment: I hear ya. I don't think it's possible, tho, unless a specific debugger offers some fancy hide-from-me feature. It's not a common debugger feature, tho.